# JVM Crash java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: memory, crash, jvm, virtual

My Java application runs on Windows Server 2008 R2 and JDK 1.6
When I monitor it with JConsole, the committed virtual memory increases continually over time, while the heap memory usage stays below 50MB.

The max heap size is 1024MB.

The application creates many small, short-lived event objects over time.  The behavior is as if each heap allocation is counted against the committed virtual memory.

When the committed virtual memory size approaches 1000MB, the application crashes with a native memory allocation failure.

## java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: requested 1024000 bytes for GrET in C:\BUILD_AREA\jdk6\hotspot\src\share\vm\utilities\growableArray.cpp. Out of swap space?

My conclusion is the virtual address space of 2GB has been exhausted.

Why does JConsole show the committed virtual address space growing over time even though the heap is not growing over time?

Comment: http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.com/2012/03/outofmemoryerror-out-of-swap-space.html

Comment: Is running a more modern JVM and/or OS an option? Can you reduce the max heap size?